# a Problem about Harmonic Function

Tags: elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$, $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $p>1$ satisfies
$$\int_{\Omega}|\triangledown u|^{p-2}\triangledown u\triangledown\phi=0~~~,\forall\phi\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$$
Then we call $u$ harmonic function.

- When $p=n$, prove $u\in C^\alpha(\Omega)$
- When $p<n$, prove $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega)$

I wonder how to prove two questions. The hints say that the former is proved by Caccioppoli inequality; the latter by Moser iteration.

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Crossposted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209744/a-problem-about-a-harmonic-function

Comment: The functions you are considering are usually known as p-harmonic functions and the equation is the p-Laplace equation. You should start by perusing the lecture notes of Peter Lindqvist: http://www.math.ntnu.no/~lqvist/p-laplace.pdf